# Row names & column names in R

Tags: r, r-rownames, r-colnames

Do the following function pairs generate exactly the same results?

Pair 1) `names()` & `colnames()`

Pair 2) `rownames()` & `row.names()`

Comment: Why not run them and find out?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As Oscar Wilde said

> Consistency is the last refuge of the
>   unimaginative.

R is more of an evolved rather than designed language, so these things happen. `names()` and `colnames()` work on a `data.frame` but `names()` does not work on a matrix:

```
R> DF <- data.frame(foo=1:3, bar=LETTERS[1:3])
R> names(DF)
[1] "foo" "bar"
R> colnames(DF)
[1] "foo" "bar"
R> M <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3, dimnames=list(1:3, c("alpha","beta","gamma")))
R> names(M)
NULL
R> colnames(M)
[1] "alpha" "beta"  "gamma"
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply with an example. So does it mean that it is always convenient to use `colnames()` instead of `names()`? Is there a similar situation for row names?

Comment: There are differences between data types.

Comment: Emerson said: "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines. With consistency a great soul has simply nothing to do."

Comment: and Larry Wall said "I know it's weird, but it does make it easier to write poetry"  http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.perl/msg/5b26830b9e52189e

Comment: colnames DOES work on matrix, it is explicitly stated in the manual.

Comment: @Tomas: Look at my example. I *show* that `colnames` works on both, but `names` does not.  Which address the OP's point 1.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel aha your example is fine, but you write *"names() and colnames() work on a data.frame but not on a matrix"* which is apparently FALSE :-)

Comment: The AND makes it true. Both do not work on both. Only one of them does.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel good programmer joke! :-)) But the fact you haven't corrected it makes me worry that you weren't joking? I guess we both know that in human language this is understood differently, as "names() work on .... AND colnames() work on ....".

Comment: I really do not have time for this. The OP accepted the answer, 20+ people upvoted it, and *my example still stands*. If you still think you know better, I won't convince you.  I already gave you two relevant answers.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I upvoted your answer, but Tomas is correct that "and" is used in the English language differently than in logic/programming. As it stands now, that sentence reads incorrectly. If you have some time, can you please make that sentence more clear? "colnames() works on both dataframes and matrices, but names() works only on dataframes."

Comment: Efficiency is the last priority of the imaginative

Answer (score 8):

Just to expand a little on Dirk's example:

It helps to think of a data frame as a list with equal length vectors.  That's probably why `names` works with a data frame but not a matrix.

The other useful function is `dimnames` which returns the names for every dimension.  You will notice that the `rownames` function actually just returns the first element from `dimnames`.

Regarding `rownames` and `row.names`: I can't tell the difference, although `rownames` uses `dimnames` while `row.names` was written outside of R.  They both also seem to work with higher dimensional arrays:

```
>a <- array(1:5, 1:4)
> a[1,,,]
> rownames(a) <- "a"
> row.names(a)
[1] "a"
> a
, , 1, 1    
  [,1] [,2]
a    1    2

> dimnames(a)
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL
```

Comment: This is a better answer. Snark is funny, but knowledge is more useful. a `data.frame` indeed is usable both as a list of columns and a matrix, i.e. each column has the same length and you can extract single rows or subsets of rows.

Answer (score 5):

I think that using `colnames` and `rownames` makes the most sense; here's why.

Using `names` has several disadvantages.  You have to remember that it means "column names", and it only works with data frame, so you'll need to call `colnames` whenever you use matrices. By calling `colnames`, you only have to remember one function.  Finally, if you look at the code for `colnames`, you will see that it calls `names` in the case of a data frame anyway, so the output is identical.

`rownames` and `row.names` return the same values for data frame and matrices; the only difference that I have spotted is that where there aren't any names, `rownames` will print "NULL" (as does `colnames`), but `row.names` returns it invisibly.  Since there isn't much to choose between the two functions, `rownames` wins on the grounds of aesthetics, since it pairs more prettily with`colnames`.  (Also, for the lazy programmer, you save a character of typing.)

Answer (score 2):

And another expansion:

```
# create dummy matrix
set.seed(10)
m <- matrix(round(runif(25, 1, 5)), 5)
d <- as.data.frame(m)
```

If you want to assign new column names you can do following on `data.frame`:

```
# an identical effect can be achieved with colnames()   
names(d) <- LETTERS[1:5]
> d
  A B C D E
1 3 2 4 3 4
2 2 2 3 1 3
3 3 2 1 2 4
4 4 3 3 3 2
5 1 3 2 4 3
```

If you, however run previous command on `matrix`, you'll mess things up:

```
names(m) <- LETTERS[1:5]
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    2    4    3    4
[2,]    2    2    3    1    3
[3,]    3    2    1    2    4
[4,]    4    3    3    3    2
[5,]    1    3    2    4    3
attr(,"names")
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
[20] NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Since matrix can be regarded as two-dimensional vector, you'll assign names only to first five values (you don't want to do that, do you?). In this case, you should stick with `colnames()`.

So there...